# Could we use "invite" as a noun in some cases

Tags: word-usage, nouns

> And as many have several **invites**, they're happy to give some away - especially when they've been up all night. You need to ask nicely and may not always be lucky as competition is fierce.

Is the above usage of the word ***invite*** commonly accepted as standard English nowadays? I'm asking because I found many occurrences of this usage on Internet, among which the above piece is taken from The Guardian newspaper. If I am not wrong, it seems that such a Agnès Poirier, the journalist, uses "invite" as a noun.

Answer (score 7):

*Invite* has been used as a noun since at least 1659. There's no good reason to stop now, but it is considered colloquial and for that reason is probably best avoided in the most formal contexts.

Comment: Note the "formal" noun form is *invitation*.

Comment: Oald labels "invite" as informal for the normal noun invitation.